# How to pass default value into material datepicker using formly?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-formly

I have problem with Angular 8 nad material and formly. I configured formlyField like this:

```
{
  key: 'releaseDate',
  type: 'datepicker',
  defaultValue: new Date(this.data.releaseDate.split('\\.')[2] + '.' + this.data.releaseDate.split('\\.')[1] + '.' + this.data.releaseDate.split('\\.')[0]),
  templateOptions: {
    label: 'data wydania',
    placeholder: 'Wpisz date wydania',
    required: true,
    datepickerOptions: {format: 'yyyy.MM.dd'},
    datepickerPopup: 'yyyy.MM.dd'
  }
}
```

I don't know how to pass default value to show view on chrome. What format should I use and what date should I pass into default value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass a Date type: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp

In this example, you set the current date as default value:

```
{
  key: 'Datepicker',
  type: 'datepicker',
  defaultValue: new Date(),
  templateOptions: {
    label: 'Datepicker',
    placeholder: 'Placeholder',
    description: 'Description',
    required: true,
  },
}
```

In this example, you set the 24 December of 2018 as default value.

```
{
  key: 'Datepicker',
  type: 'datepicker',
  defaultValue: new Date(2018, 11, 24),
  templateOptions: {
    label: 'Datepicker',
    placeholder: 'Placeholder',
    description: 'Description',
    required: true,
  },
}
```